# Handling dependencies of plugin

Tags: java

I am writing a plugin for Axway api gateway. I packaged all the dependencies with the code as a uber jar. When doing this, the jar on my plugin is clashing with the axway jars and getting weird exceptions.

How to isolate the plugin jar dependencies from Axway jars to avoid clash? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running these jars  ? Are these packaged and deployed in an application container ? or do you run these uber jars standalone ?

Comment: Depending on how are you assembling this jar I would recommend to mark the dependencies of your jar as provided (if it is a maven project)

Comment: They are packaged and deployed in ext/lib folder of Axway. Not a standalone jar

Comment: Uber JAR will not work, as you have to specify a class loader that capable of loading he JARs inside...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto how to specify the class loader for uber jar?

Comment: Is it possible to package all the dependencies as a separate jar  and ask the application jar to load from the dependency jars which is in a separate directory?

Comment: The uber JAR does this for itself, when executing it as a standalone program. If you want to create a library (like your plugin) you have to specify depending libraries in your ˙/META-INF/manifest.mf` file.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thanks. Do you mind sharing an example for achieving this.

Comment: Use multibinders using Guice, it will resolve your plugin issue.

Comment: @Tehmina, Can you explain a little bit more. I looked at their documentation, I didnt understand much

Comment: Consider the given links, https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings  https://thedet.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/guice-2-0-multibinder-java-serviceloader-plugin-mechanism/

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I created a simple jar without any dependencies and place it in the classpath of Axway. The simple jar will then invoke the uber jar in a separate class loader to handle the request and give back the results. And it works like charm.